# mod_rewrite string and integer only

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I Need to rewrite URL only when the URL is string and integer

For Example :

```
http://domain.com/abc12
```

OR

```
http://domain.com/123
```

I Try to use this Rule

```
RewriteRule ([A-Za-z0-9]) file.php?key=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but this rewrite files like .html and .php ..etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add bounds to the regular expression, specifically the `^` (beginning of match) and the `$` (end of match).

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ file.php?key=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @J.youjaz also note that if you have other rules, you'll need to order them in the order you want them to be applied.